# Using Google Sheets to document ID swipes from a magstrip reader?

Tags: google-sheets

So I work as a student employee at my college and part of my job is to check people in and out. I've been doing this manually by looking at their ID and writing the information, but I am trying to find a way to use ID swipes on a magstripe reader to streamline the process. When I swipe a school ID on the reader, it'll type an entry like:

;21944**931924914**916932586267152894?

Where the bold part is the actual ID number and everything else isn't relevant (at least to me). I found an easy solution using a python program just to turn it into a string, get rid of the semicolon and the question mark, and then use math to remove everything except for the ID number. Is there any way in Google Sheets to just have them swipe their ID, the raw ID data get inputted into a cell, and then use some kind of function/other feature to just isolate the bolded ID code?

Another idea that I think is less likely to be possible is I'd want to find a way to link the ID number and their name. That way I don't have to have them swipe their ID number and then manually type in their name too. I wish I knew of a way that they could just swipe their ID and it would automatically input all the information I need since the current process is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `;21944931924914916932586267152894?` is in cell `A2`, you can extract the nine characters that comprise the ID, starting at the seventh character, with this formula:

`=mid(A2, 7, 9)`

To automatically do the same with all values in the column `A2:A`, use this array formula in row 2 of a free column:

`=arrayformula( mid(A2:A, 7, 9) )`

To find the name that corresponds with an ID, use the [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318) function.